# Joining tables with case statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have been trying to join 4 tables with case statement on its 4th table
Unfortunately my data was doubled and it is not the latest data on each table. Please help.

QUERY :

```
SELECT
d.serial_no, d.dummy_serial ,
a.model_id, b.model_id, c.model_id, d.model_id,
MAX(a.create_date), MAX(b.create_date), MAX(c.create_date), MAX(d.create_date)
FROM table1 as a
JOIN table2 as b
ON a.serial_no = b.serial_no
JOIN table3 as c
ON b.serial_no = c.serial_no
JOIN table4 as d
ON c.serial_no =
(CASE WHEN
a.model_id = 'LB31' AND
b.model_id = 'LB31' AND
c.model_id = 'LB31' AND
d.model_id = 'LB31'
THEN d.dummy_serial
ELSE d.serial_no END );
```

**WHAT I WANT**

[image]

Comment: you should use `group by` when aggregating.

Answer (score 1):

The query was missing a `group by` clause. All the columns not being aggregated and in the `select` should be grouped.

```
SELECT
d.serial_no, d.dummy_serial ,
a.model_id, b.model_id, c.model_id, d.model_id,
MAX(a.create_date), MAX(b.create_date), MAX(c.create_date), MAX(d.create_date)
FROM table1 as a
JOIN table2 as b
ON a.serial_no = b.serial_no
JOIN table3 as c
ON b.serial_no = c.serial_no
JOIN table4 as d
ON c.serial_no =
(CASE WHEN
 a.model_id = 'LB31' AND
 b.model_id = 'LB31' AND
 c.model_id = 'LB31' AND
 d.model_id = 'LB31'
 THEN d.dummy_serial
 ELSE d.serial_no END)
group by d.serial_no, d.dummy_serial, a.model_id, b.model_id, c.model_id, d.model_id
```

Comment: great ! the only problem is it doesnt select latest model_id on its table. should i enclose model_id on MAX() function also ?